# Cannot find module '@agm/core'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, google-maps

I am trying to use Google maps in my angular 4 app.
I am using Angular 4 and Nodejs 8.

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'GOOGLEAPIKEY'
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Please help me ??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> npm install @agm/core --save

This command solved my problem.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.. Just run :

```
npm uninstall @agm/core -s
npm install @agm/core -s
```

Comment: yes this is  the right answer to uninstall first then re install again ..... thncx @christophe

Comment: @ABDULLAHMAKKI it worked for me and two other people apparently. Happy coding and have fun.

Answer (score -1):

It cannot find the module because you forgot to add it in your NgModule in imports :P :

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'GOOGLEAPIKEY'
    })
  ],
```

Best regards ;)

Comment: Thanks and Yes, I have modified the code.Please have a look.But still same error.

Comment: Did you do a : npm install @agm/core --save ?