# ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/http/src/version.d.ts(13,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

While building my angular 4 based application i am getting below error.

ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/http/src/version.d.ts(13,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

Could you please suggest what to do?

Comment: Delete `node_modules` folder and `npm i` or `yarn`

Comment: Still no success as it is unable to download @angualr/http folder

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081665/cannot-find-module-agm-core/53918843#53918843

Comment: @Vishal :You rescued me..thanks

Comment: You are welcome...